# Error while creating object to be consumed in in asp.net core controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having error when creating an object in javascript

I'm having this generic error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

That's why i can't solve it. it didn't have specific error message.

This is my model

```
[Serializable, JsonObject]
    public class CompleteOrderRequest : BaseMessageRequest<CompleteOrderRequestDto>
    {

    }

[Serializable]
    [JsonObject, Bind("RequestFrom,RequestBy")]
    public abstract class BaseMessageRequest<T> : IBaseMessageRequest<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        protected BaseMessageRequest()
        {
            Request = new T();
        }

        

        [Required, StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true), BindRequired]
        [FromQuery]
        public string RequestBy { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]//, BindRequired]
        [FromQuery]
        public T Request { get; set; }
    }

public class CompleteOrderRequestDto
    {

        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        
    }
```

This is my controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PayNow([FromBody] CompleteOrderRequest request)
            {
                
                return View();
            }
```

And this is my javascript code.

```
var CompleteOrderRequest = {};
    CompleteOrderRequest.RequestBy = 'test';
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Orders/PayNow/${CompleteOrderRequest}',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```

The error is in this line. I'm encountering error before calling the controller.

```
CompleteOrderRequest.RequestBy = 'test';
```

So what's wrong with what Am i doing? And I'm receiving this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: What javascript has to do with c#? you can't call c# methods from javascript directly. Pls show the whole javascript code

Comment: @Serge i updated the code. I can't create a model in javascript. so i can't call the controller.

Answer (score 0):

fix the ajax

```
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Orders/PayNow',
               data: { request: CompleteOrderRequest}
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```

and when you use only one kind of data from ajax , you don't usually need [FromBody]. Try to change the action too

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PayNow(CompleteOrderRequest request)
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your object in JavaScript, you can declare the properties inline like this:

```
var CompleteOrderRequest = {
    RequestBy: "test"
};
```

You'd also need to ensure you provide that object as the `data` parameter when posting with `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `[FromBody]` in action,you need to change your `contentType` to `application/json` and convert `CompleteOrderRequest` to json type:

```
var CompleteOrderRequest = {};
            CompleteOrderRequest.RequestBy = 'test';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Orders/PayNow',
                data: JSON.stringify(CompleteOrderRequest),
                contentType:"application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {

                    }
                }
            });
```